# Match a substring from last ":" of a match string

Tags: regex, substring

i want get substring from a string match with this pattern:

```
:((?![{\[\-\d])([^,}]+))

match all string value.
```

for example:

```
altitude{altitudeValue:52420,altitudeConfidence:alt-002-00}}},
highFrequencyContainer:basicVehicleContainerHighFrequency:
{heading{headingValue:3601,headingConfidence:127},speed{speedValue:0,speedConfidence:127},
driveDirection:unavailable
```

i match with pattern above this strings:

```
:alt-002-00
:basicVehicleContainerHighFrequency:{heading{headingValue:3601
:unavailable
```

but I want:

```
:alt-002-00
NO: **:3601**  <--match from last ":" to end of previous match (is possible with regex?) only if is a 
string.
YES: if was **:hello** <-match because is a string
:unavailable
```

i want match from last ":" to end of previous match (is possible with regex?).
How change my pattern rule? `:((?![{\[\-\d])([^,}]+))`

thanks
regards

Comment: Do you want to match anything after a colon if it contains alphabetic characters(technically, '3601' would be a string in this context)?

Comment: yes string after last ":"

Comment: @Catanzaro Did any of the solutions work out?

Answer (score 0):

If you replace in your regex `([^,}]+)` with: `(?:(?:(?!:\d)[^,}])+)`, then it will not scan past a colon followed by a digit:

```
import re

s = """altitude{altitudeValue:52420,altitudeConfidence:alt-002-00}}},
highFrequencyContainer:basicVehicleContainerHighFrequency:
{heading{headingValue:3601,headingConfidence:127},speed{speedValue:0,speedConfidence:127},
driveDirection:unavailable"""

re.findall(r'(?::(?![{\[\-\d])(?:(?:(?!:\d)[^,}])+))', s)
```

Prints:

```
[':alt-002-00',
 ':basicVehicleContainerHighFrequency:\n{heading{headingValue',
 ':unavailable']
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/miVT92/1/)

Note that there are no capture groups (other than 0) in the above regex.

Comment: i dont want  :basicVehicleContainerHighFrequency:\n{heading{headingValue

Comment: And what about this string eliminates that from consideration besides just saying you don't want it?

Answer (score 0):

Matching from the last `:` can be done by adding `:` to the negated character class. To get the submatch, you can use a single capturing group instead of 2.

```
:((?![{\[\d-])[^:,}]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `:`Match literally
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `(?![{\[\d-])` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not `{` `[` a digit or `-`
  - `[^:,}]+` Match 1+ times any char other than `:` `,` `}`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5qc5C/1)